# What are the negative health effects of Absolute Zero Monster Energy

Tags: caffeine

I consume one 473ml can of Absolutely Zero Monster energy in the morning and another one at around 3pm. I consider these important otherwise i can't get into gear in the morning and begin to fall asleep at my desk in the afternoon. My lifestyle choices are irrelevant to this question.

The drink claims to contain absolutely no sugar, and no calories, and appears to be mainly Sodium water and vitamins. As far as Ive researched Caffine has no actual negative health impacts, and the other ingredients seem almost harmless.

Monster carries the stigma that it is extremely unhealthy. I would like to know besides the caffeine dependance, what actually are the negative impacts it will have on my health?

Nutritional information here: 
https://www.fatsecret.com/calories-nutrition/monster-beverage/absolutely-zero

It is interesting to note that a large Starbucks coffee contains more caffeine, sugar and other 'unhealthy' ingredients but is considered to be less damaging than Monster

Comment: *My lifestyle choices are irrelevant to this question* Quite bold argument I think. Let´s say need for stimulant is due to lack of sleep. Do you still think life choices are irrelevant, especially since the context in this question is your health.

Answer (score 0):

So far daily caffeine intake has not proven to be too dangerous. [1] Side effects include anxiety, jitteriness and insomnia[2], which may affect your psychical balance, and may worsen several psychiatric disorders. You may also search for effects and complications of insomnia, as this is one of the major problems.  Note that large coffeine intake may be dangerous in pregnancy.

"I consider these important otherwise i can't get into gear in the morning and begin to fall asleep at my desk in the afternoon. My lifestyle choices are irrelevant to this question." - in my opinion this may have more serious effect on your health than caffeine intake, but as you already noted thats not your question.

[1 - pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12519715)

[2 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine#Side_effects)

Comment: The question is very relevant, but as in current form it is focusing only to one side of **energy drinks** in general. The answers should discuss energy drink as a whole, not only caffeine since energy drinks contains a lot of other, possibly, toxic substances. For example, this study published in a quality medical journal should be discussed: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3065144/pdf/zpe511.pdf

Comment: true that. Nevertheless the author did not ask about "energy drinks" in general which may contain thousands of different substances, but for a special product. None of the ingredients of this product is known to be seriosly dangerous in the given dosage.